# Is there a way to draw a Point on a Polar Chart

Tags: c#, charts, diagram

I want to add a colored point (red or green) on every "crossing" between the rings and segment lines. Is there a simpler way than making 240 Series which just have two datapoints?

[image: The chart i want the points added to]

Comment: In all cases where I have used Polar graphs like the one you have above the velocity or rate of change was important.  So I find it interesting that you want to put a single dot on the 1 hour boundaries.  It is possible that you are putting an average of the previous hour on a dot on the line,  so then I get that case.   In your situation I would manipulate the final data to the polar graph render code.  The Modified data would just have one data point for each hour – 24 data points per day on the hour ( 15 degree interval).   I would experiment in Excel first.

Comment: I have a dictionary that has a boolean value for each point and I basically want to show if it is true or false. There is no rate of change after all the data is in the dictionary it is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - There is no need to create different `Series`. Just add the `DataPoints` you want at the spots you want! This is the easiest way, since you already know the values.

2 - As an alternative you can use a `xxxPaint` event and draw filled circles (or whatever you fancy..). For this you need to convert the values to pixels. This can **usually** be achieved with the `AxisX/AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition`  methods. **However** for `Polar Charts` this will not work. Instead you need to calculate the pixel coordinates yourself..

The 2nd way is a bit harder, but of course will give you more control over the style of the points you draw..

Here is the result of adding `DataPoints`:

[image]

Example code for the 1st version; first we set up a polar chart with its axis properties:

```
Chart chart = chart2;
chart.Series.Clear();

ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
Axis ay = ca.AxisY;

ax.Minimum  = 0;
ax.Maximum  = 360;
ax.Interval = 15;   // 15° interval
ax.Crossing = 0;    // start the segments at the top!

ay.Minimum  = 0;
ay.Maximum  = 10;
ay.Interval = 1;


Series s0 = chart.Series.Add("points");
s0.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;   
s0.SetCustomProperty("PolarDrawingStyle", "Marker");
s0.MarkerSize = 6; 
s0.MarkerColor = Color.Teal;
s0.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Polar;
```

And then we add the points at the crossings and finally style one of them to show that they all can be different..:

```
for (double vx = ax.Minimum; vx < ax.Maximum; vx += ax.Interval)
    for (double vy = ay.Minimum; vy <= ay.Maximum; vy += ay.Interval)
        s0.Points.AddXY(vx, vy);

s0.Points[333].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
s0.Points[333].MarkerSize = 12;
```

---

For the code to calculate the pixel coordinates [see this post!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453848/hittest-in-polar-chart-with-multiple-series/38458511?s=1|2.0256#38458511)

Using the function in the link and this `PrePaint` event:

```
private void chart2_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Chart chart = chart2;
    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
    Series s0 = chart.Series["points"];

    foreach (DataPoint dp in s0.Points)
    {
        PointF pt = PolarValueToPixelPosition(dp, chart, ca);
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.OrangeRed, pt.X - 5, pt.Y - 5, 9, 9);
    }
}
```

we can adorn each point with a circle:

[image]

Or course, if you don't want to add the `DataPoints` in the first place, you can replace them by calculating the values like I did in the loops that added them..

Comment: Thank you so much! Used the first one and it works perfectly.

Comment: I implimeted it but I have a new question related to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828410/changing-a-c-sharp-graph-from-polar-do-radar please help me. Thank you.