# Is it possible to have line chart with 'markers' for one data point in C# Charting?

Tags: c#

My objective is to plot a live Time vs Temperature (Line chart) from a device. In that I'm checking each temperature value with a logic to find out my appropriate temperature value. 
After finding the appropriate temperature, how to highlight/mark that particular point only in my Line chart and continue reading my temperature?

```
livedataChart.Series.Add("Temperature");
livedataChart.Series["Temperature"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
for ()
    {
     Check(maintemperature);
     livedataChart.Series["Temperature"].Points.AddXY(time, maintemperature);
    }

private void Check(double temp)
    {            
        if (somelogic with temp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Appropriate Temperature is calculated");
        }
    }
```

I have tried adding another series (Chart Type as Points) and gave the appropriate temperature in the point series. I got a point near to the Y-axis which is of no use. All i want is to have a point in the running Temperature Line graph.

Comment: You can set a MarkerStyle/Color/size per DataPoint .

Comment: @TaW Thanks for your response. But It changes to all the data points. Could you please tell how to set MarkerStyle/Color/Size for a Single DataPoint?

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065172/is-there-a-way-to-draw-a-point-on-a-polar-chart/39066079#39066079)