# Get Form.Left value of Point(X,Y) in ChartControl

Tags: c#, charts, position, converters, datapoint

I need the Left value (Or the Location on the screen) of a specific point in a Chart Control.
Basiclly the 0,0 Point, because it changes when resizing the Form.

cheers

Comment: if you want it to change while resizing the form you can change the anchor of the chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the position of a `DataPoint` with `XValue = 0` and `YValue[0] = 0` you can use the `XAxis` function `ValueToPixelPosition` for this; here is an example, which assumes you have added a `Label lbl`  to the chart's `Controls` and will keep that `Label` sitting at the position of the 3rd `DataPoint`:

```
private void chart1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataPoint dp = chart1.Series[0].Points[2];
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;

    int px = (int) ax.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue);
    int py = (int) ay.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]);

    lbl.Location = new Point(px, py);
}
```

Do note that this function as well as the other conversion functions (`PixelPositionToValue`) will only work either in the `Pre/PostPaint` events or in mouse events. The `Resize` event also seems to work.

Using them at other time, most notably before the chart is done with its layout, will either produce wrong or null values.

[image]

The px, py pixel values are relative to the Chart. To convert them to a Point relative to the Form you can use the usual conversion functions [`PointToScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`PointToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

**Update:**

If you actually want the pixel coordinates of the top left of the `ChartArea.InnerPlotPosition` you can use [these two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453848/hittest-in-polar-chart-with-multiple-series/38458511#38458511):

```
RectangleF ChartAreaClientRectangle(Chart chart, ChartArea CA)
{
    RectangleF CAR = CA.Position.ToRectangleF();
    float pw = chart.ClientSize.Width / 100f;
    float ph = chart.ClientSize.Height / 100f;
    return new RectangleF(pw * CAR.X, ph * CAR.Y, pw * CAR.Width, ph * CAR.Height);
}

RectangleF InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(Chart chart, ChartArea CA)
{
    RectangleF IPP = CA.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();
    RectangleF CArp = ChartAreaClientRectangle(chart, CA);

    float pw = CArp.Width / 100f;
    float ph = CArp.Height / 100f;

    return new RectangleF(CArp.X + pw * IPP.X, CArp.Y + ph * IPP.Y,
                            pw * IPP.Width, ph * IPP.Height);
}
```

Use it maybe in the `Resize` event like this:

```
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Rectangle ipr = Rectangle.Round(InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(chart1, ca));
lbl.Location =  ipr.Location;
```

[image]

You can easily offset it by a few pixels if you want now..

Comment: Hi,

that is basiclly what I am looking for, but I dont want to attach the label to a Datapoint.

I want the label to be attached to the upper left corner of the chart. 
And to stay there.

Image :
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pk41k5l5pag3d5/chart.png?dl=0)

cheers

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer to show how to stick the label to the top left portion of the inner chart area.

Comment: Pefect answer :D
Thats exactly wht I was looking for.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

this was the Code I needed. It keeps the labels close to the upper left corner while resizeing the chart. Also when the Y Axis moves, the labels stick to it.

Thanks to @TaW for providing the needed Code (See answer 1)

```
            ChartArea ca = prodChart.ChartAreas[0];

            Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
            Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
            int px = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(ax.Minimum + (ax.Maximum * 0.01));
            int py = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Maximum - (ay.Maximum * 0.02));
            px = px - 5;
            qtyLabel.Location = new Point(px, py);
            sheetNameLabel.Location = new Point(px, py + 17);
            dateRangeLabel.Location = new Point(px, py + 34);
```

Comment: The same effect is what you get from the 2nd part of the answer but without relying on a maximum being set.